# Pluggable website capability with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pluggable

I can see that something similar has already been asked, and that an answer was given here:

[how to create pluggable ASP.Net website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740768/how-to-create-pluggable-asp-net-website)

However, I wonder if someone can go into a little more detail.

I have a website that I want to allow developers to create plugins for. A classic example of the functionality I want is something like Umbraco or Orchard in the way that a developer can create a control, and then import it into the system for it to be useable.

Ideally, someone could create a user control of some kind and that user control can be used by the website.

Is there any examples of where this has been done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first determine where you want to support extensibility within your application (security, UI, business logic, etc.) and then you define an adapter between your core logic and the plugin (this your interface or interfaces) and then you build types that implement your interfaces.  see [Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx) on MSDN.